# How can I include URL params when programmatically navigating using the history API (not Links)?

Tags: reactjs, react-router

I have a web-app where I would like to introduce URL params <:param> to enforce the URL schema. In order to navigate, I am using the [history API](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router/docs/api/history.md) to push new URLs onto the history stack.

1. My first objective is to require the :query parameter in '/category?query=:query'
2. My second object is to then constrain this to 1 or more characters (.+)

I have tried this a few different ways:

```
const OLD_PATHS = {
  CATEGORY_PAGE     : '/category',
  CATEGORY_PAGE_TAB : '/category/:subcategory'
}

const NEW_PATHS = {
  CATEGORY_PAGE_BASE: '/category',
  CATEGORY_PAGE     : '/category?query=:query',
  CATEGORY_PAGE_TAB : '/category/:subcategory?query=:query'
};

searchCategoryV1() {
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname: OLD_PATHS.CATEGORY_PAGE,
      search: `?query=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.query)}`,
      state: {query: this.state.query }
  });
}

searchSubCategoryV1() {
  this.props.history.push({
      pathname:  OLD_PATHS.CATEGORY_PAGE += `/${searchCategory}`,
      search: `?q=${encodeURIComponent(this.state.query)}`,
      state: { query: this.state.query }
  });

searchCategoryV2() {
  this.props.history.push(
    _.replace(NEW_PATHS.CATEGORY_PAGE, ":query", this.state.query),
    {query: this.state.query}
  );
}

searchSubCategoryV2(subcategory) {
  this.props.history.push(
    `${NEW_PATHS.CATEGORY_PAGE_BASE}/${subcategory}?query=${this.state.query}`,
    {query: this.state.query}
  );
}
```

When I am not attempting to enforce the URL schema, I am able to programmatically navigate. However, attempting to require the 'query' parameter has not resulted in this route working! Please help me understand what to do here, it would be much appreciated!

Comment: 1. Query params aren't required. 2. They're referred to as search in React Router's `location`: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/query-parameters

Comment: Frequently I see them interpolated into the string without using location.search to pass them to react. I guess my question is really on how to use the API correctly

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure I understand your intent, but perhaps this might work... where it allows you to add/remove queries manually via user interactions and/or by navigating through browser history (mouse back and forward). It'll also persist queries across page refreshes.

If you absolutely need to use a `params` option, then I'd place it within the Route's `path` and access it via `(this.props.)location.params`. If it needs to be dynamically replaced, then you're better off moving it within the query params like so: `/movies/action?subcategory=comedy&year=2019&starring=Bob%20Saget`. When you start swapping out params, then your Route structure can become unnecessarily cluttered and harder to manage.

Notes: This example utilizes [qs](https://www.npmjs.com/package/qs) to parse `(this.props.)location.search` to a simple string and an object of queries. In addition, it also uses a [render prop](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BcVAq3YFiuc) (see `pages/Homes/index.js` for example) to pass parent `state` to a child as `props` through a `function`.

**Demo**:

https://c7isk.csb.app/

**Source**:

[image: Edit RRD - Query Filters]

---

**components/QueryHandler**

```
import { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
import { withRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import { setQuery, stringifyQuery } from "../../utils";

class QueryHandler extends PureComponent {
  state = setQuery(this.props.location.search);

  static getDerivedStateFromProps = ({ location }) => setQuery(location.search);

  pushToLocation = query =>
    this.props.history.push(`${this.props.location.pathname}?${query}`);

  updateQuery = nextQuery =>
    this.pushToLocation(
      stringifyQuery({
        ...this.state.queries,
        ...nextQuery
      })
    );

  clearFilters = () => this.props.history.push(this.props.location.pathname);

  render = () =>
    this.props.children({
      ...this.state,
      clearFilters: this.clearFilters,
      updateQuery: this.updateQuery
    });
}

QueryHandler.propTypes = {
  children: PropTypes.func.isRequired,
  history: PropTypes.shape({
    push: PropTypes.func.isRequired
  }),
  location: PropTypes.shape({
    pathname: PropTypes.string,
    search: PropTypes.string
  })
};

export default withRouter(QueryHandler);
```

**components/Filters**

```
import React, { PureComponent } from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

class Filters extends PureComponent {
  handleChange = ({ target: { name, value } }) => {
    this.props.updateQuery({ [name]: value });
  };

  clearQuery = name => {
    this.props.updateQuery({ [name]: null });
  };

  render = () => {
    const currentQuery = {
      eventdate: "",
      eventtype: "",
      teamid: "",
      ...this.props.queries
    };

    return (
      <div style={{ margin: "0 auto", width: 500 }}>
        <div className="filter-container">
          <label className="label" htmlFor="eventdate">
            Event Date:
          </label>
          <input
            className="uk-input"
            name="eventdate"
            type="date"
            value={currentQuery.eventdate}
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          {currentQuery.eventdate && (
            <button
              className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => this.clearQuery("eventdate")}
            >
              X
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="filter-container">
          <label className="label" htmlFor="eventtype">
            Event Type:
          </label>
          <select
            name="eventtype"
            value={currentQuery.eventtype}
            className="uk-select"
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          >
            <option value="" disabled hidden>
              Select your option
            </option>
            <option value="game">Game</option>
            <option value="practice">Practice</option>
            <option value="promo">Promo</option>
          </select>
          {currentQuery.eventtype && (
            <button
              className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => this.clearQuery("eventtype")}
            >
              X
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        <div className="filter-container">
          <label className="label" htmlFor="teamid">
            Team ID:
          </label>
          <input
            className="uk-input"
            name="teamid"
            type="number"
            min="0"
            value={currentQuery.teamid}
            placeholder="Select a team ID..."
            onChange={this.handleChange}
          />
          {currentQuery.teamid && (
            <button
              className="uk-button uk-button-danger"
              type="button"
              onClick={() => this.clearQuery("teamid")}
            >
              X
            </button>
          )}
        </div>
        <div style={{ textAlign: "center" }}>
          <button
            className="uk-button uk-button-primary"
            type="button"
            onClick={this.props.clearFilters}
          >
            Clear All Filters
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}

Filters.propTypes = {
  queries: PropTypes.shape({
    eventdate: PropTypes.string,
    eventtype: PropTypes.string,
    teamid: PropTypes.string
  }),
  updateQuery: PropTypes.func.isRequired
};

export default Filters;
```

**utils/index.js**

```
import qs from "qs";

/**
 * Stringifies an object of query properties.
 *
 * @function stringifyQuery
 * @param {object} query
 * @returns {string}
 */
export const stringifyQuery = query => qs.stringify(query, { skipNulls: true });

/**
 * Parses a stringified query to an object of queries.
 *
 * @function parseQuery
  @param {string} query
 * @returns {object} - An object of query properties.
 */
export const parseQuery = query =>
  qs.parse(query, {
    ignoreQueryPrefix: true
  });

/**
 * Utilizes the functions above to parse and stringify a query.
 *
 * @function setQuery
 * @param {string} query
 * @returns {object}
 */
export const setQuery = query => {
  const queries = parseQuery(query);
  const queryString = stringifyQuery(queries);

  return { queries, queryString };
};
```

**pages/Home**

```
import React from "react";
import QueryHandler from "../../components/QueryHandler";
import Filters from "../../components/Filters";

function Home() {
  return (
    <div className="home">
      <QueryHandler>
        {props => (
          <>
            <Filters {...props} />
            <pre style={{ background: "#ebebeb" }}>
              <code>{JSON.stringify(props, null, 4)}</code>
            </pre>
          </>
        )}
      </QueryHandler>
    </div>
  );
}

export default Home;
```